# Remove embedded files from PDF using PDFBox

Tags: file, pdfbox, pdfa

I'm trying to remove all embedded files from PDF using PDFBox, inside a Java application. I'm using PDFBox with Java. Not command line tools.

There are many examples how to read embedded files using PDFBox. But it wasn't that simple to modify the code to remove the files.

Any working solution for that?

Comment: I'm using PDFBox with Java. Not command line tools.

Comment: btw, there are many examples how to read embedded files using PDFBox. But it wasn't that simple to modify the code to remove the files.

Comment: IIRC there are two types of embedded files, document level and annotation level. Removing annotation level should be easy, i.e. remove such `PDAnnotationFileAttachment` annotations from the page. Removing the document level files should be possible with `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getNames().setEmbeddedFiles(null);`, but I don't have much time currently.

Comment: Thanks Tilman, that is something I'm currently trying to implement. Mostly trying to remove document level embedded files.

Comment: "doc.getDocumentCatalog().getNames().setEmbeddedFiles(null)" was exactly the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer from Tilman given in a comment (but an answer is more visible thus the copy):

> IIRC there are two types of embedded files, document level and
> annotation level. Removing annotation level should be easy, i.e.
> remove such PDAnnotationFileAttachment annotations from the page.
> Removing the document level files should be possible with
> doc.getDocumentCatalog().getNames().setEmbeddedFiles(null);, but I
> don't have much time currently.

Comment: Beware, PDF/A3 and PDF-2.0 define the mechanism of associated files. The file specification dictionaries thereof can be in the embedded files names tree but don't have to be there. Thus, by removing that names tree, you don't truly remove the embedded associated files. As a consequence, viewers fully supporting the associated files mechanism will still indicate the presence of those files.